# Send google+ sign-in cookies to webview

Tags: android, android-webview, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to send cookies from Google+ sign-in Button (GoogleApiClient) to webview. Is this possible or has  anyone an idea ?

Comment: Had you tried something?

Comment: yes i'm trying for 1 week and i found no solution ...  do you have an idea how can i retrieve the cookies after login from Google+ sign-in Button (GoogleApiClient) ?

Comment: Anyone got any solution for this problem? I am trying to send my googleApiClient object to a webview which load a google form.